# Sql Default Country, City, Town lists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

i want to bring default country default city default town in every db grid in my admin panel
these are not drop down these are db grid

i have three table
 
**country table**
id(int),name(varchar),is_default enum('1','0')

**city table**
 
id(int),country_id(int),name(varchar),is_default enum('1','0')

**town table**
 
id(int),countr_id(int),city_id(int),name(varchar),is_default enum('1','0')

i have 3 link in my admin panel
 
Country list
 
City List
 
Town List

**Country List** 
 
 - when i open country list it will bring list but default country will come first

**country   default**
 
USA        yes  (its coming at first line because its is_dfault=1)
 
Germany    No

thats ok 
 
Select * from country where is_default='1'

**City List**
 
When i open that list

- City list will come with own county name, but default country will come at first line
- and default city will be first in this default country in city list page

  Select city.*,country.name as country
   
  left join country on country.id=city.id
   
  order by country.is_default,city.is_default asc
   
  thats wrong sql i know
   
  example
   
  **city name   country     default**
   
  new jersey  USA          yes (this city coming at first line because its is_default=1)
   
  chicago     USA           no
   
  koln        Germany       no (Germany cities starting after USA cities because country is default=1)

**Town List**

- is_default value 1 town will come at first with own city towns at first line
   
  example
   
  **town name      city name   country     default**
   
  usa town       newjersey   USA           1 (this town coming at first line because its is_default=1)
  after usa city towns
   
  germany town1   koln       GERMANY       0 (Germany or other country cities start after USA towns)

i think my problem is with order (order by is_default ) or i need diffirent sql with other selections
 
i tried some codes but countries coming mix and others city and towns list too
 
waiting your helps.
 
thanks

Comment: You have a city id in your town table? This implies that a town is part of a city?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether i got what you mean, and I try to give an answer.

I think what mix the countries or other column is wrong join condition.
Your sql here:

```
Select city.*,country.name as country 
    left join country on country.id=city.id
    order by country.is_default,city.is_default asc
```

Above is what you post, Because it is not complete, I guess your join condition "on country.id=city.id" is wrong. If you wanna combine the two table, on its contry id, you should

```
SELECT city.*, county.name AS country_name from 
     country LEFT JOIN city ON country.id = city.country_id
     ORDER BY country.is_default, city.is_default DESC
```

Because "is_default" is 1, I use "DESC", then default rows whill pop first.

I hope that will be helpful for you :)

Comment: @conf: Can you post some more clue? Or you may debug sql by split the sentence, test them one by one. I think it is a good way debug the complex sql sentence.

Comment: @confi: Suddenly, I have some idea. Do you mean that your **contry** and/or **city** did not appear continuous(e.g. it shoud be "china shanghai;china beijing", but now is "china shanghai;usa la;china beijing"). If that, you should add city.country_id and city.id to your order by clause, then your result will be more orderly. May that help you :).